# Spring and Camel CXF playing nicely inside a WAR

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, cxf, apache-camel

I have a web application.  It has Servlets and JSPs, etc.  Now I'm adding a web service.

I can get CXF working.  My @WebService works fine.

But I need the web service to have access to my beans, which are set up in Spring.

If I try adding the following, to forward requests to an EJB  (because this works fine for standalone apps) :

```
<bean id="webServ" class="com.company.application.MyWebServiceHandler" />

<camelContext id="FindCode" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="FindCodeRoute">
        <from uri="cxf:bean:myEndpoint?dataFormat=POJO" />
        <to uri="log:input?showAll=true&amp;level=INFO"/>
        <to uri="bean:webServ?method=process" />
        <to uri="log:input?showAll=true&amp;level=INFO" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

It gives me "Cannot find any registered HttpDestinationFactory from the Bus."
I've Googled the hell out of this.

I've got

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-xml.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>
```

and I've tried importing

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

and/or
        
            org.apache.cxf
            cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty
            2.7.13

But nope.

Does anyone know how to inject an EJB into a WebService?

If I slap a @Stateless on the @WebService, it doesn't find my injected EJBs.  NPE.  I'm using JBoss EAP 6.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using camel-example-cxf-tomcat as a basis.

Comment: you should explain what was the exact resolution, problem. Also provide the links for this camel-example.

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/cxf-tomcat-example.html - I don't know what fixed it.  I think the problem was that I had cxf:bean:handlerName instead of cxf:handlerName